# Few confusing things about locks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I know how to use locks in my app, but there still few things that I don't quite understand about locking ( BTW - I know that the lock statement is just a shorthand notation for working with Monitor class type ).

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx:

```
 public class TestThreading
 {
     private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();

     public void Function()
     {

         lock (lockThis)
         {
            // Access thread-sensitive resources.
         }
     }
  }
```

> The argument provided to the lock keyword must be an object based on a reference 
>   type, and is used to define the scope of the lock. In the example above, the lock scope is limited to this function because no references to the object lockThis exist outside the function. If such a reference did exist, lock scope would extend to that object.

a) I don’t understand how lockThis object defines the scope of the lock. Scope of the lock is all the  code between ***lock(lockThis){*** and adjacent ***}***, so what exactly is it meant by *“lock scope would extend to that object”*?

b) What does the term *locking on object lockThis*  mean? Simply that we use a reference to lockThis to lock a region of code? Thus, the term doesn't suggest that we locked lockThis object?

thanx

Replying to David Morton:

I apologize if my reply is a bit long winded, but I couldn't think of any other way to word my questions and still be somewhat coherent:

> 1. The scope of the lock, in this situation, is the individual instance of the class itself. This is opposed to crossing all instance of the specific class. You could have your lock cross all instances TestThreading by making lockThis static. That's what's meant by the "scope" of the lock: whether it's applicable to a single instance, or applicable to every instance of a particular type.
>
> Other objects could still access lockThis from another thread, but they wouldn't be able to process code that is surrounded by a lock on that object.

If we call the code surrounded by lock ( located inside *TestThreading.Function* ) **C**, then since *TestThreading.Function* is not static, each *TestThreading* instance has its own copy of **C**. But if *TestThreading.Function* was static, then all *TestThreading* instances would share the same copy of **C**. As an analogy, if **C** is a room and if *TestThreading.Function* is not static, then each *TestThreading* instance would have its own **C room**, but if function was static, then all *TestThreading* instances would share the same **C room**.

Following that analogy, I interpret *lockThis* as a key to **room C**. If *lockThis* is static and if *TestThreading.Function* is not static, then  all *TestThreading* instances would use same key to enter their own **C rooms**.

- Thus, I don’t see any significance in *lockThis* being static or not, since in either case each *TestThreading* instance will use *lockThis* to enter its own *room C* ( assuming TestThreading.Function is not static ). Thus, following that logic, shouldn't the scope of the lock always be individual instance of the class (assuming TestThreading.Function is not static )?
- Similarly, I don’t see any significance in *lockThis* being private or public, since again *TestThreading* instance will use *lockThis* to enter its own **room C**( assuming *TestThreading.Function* is not static)

Second reply to David Morton

> In response to your response: There is a significance. If TestThreading.Function is static, then lockThis has to be static, otherwise, TestThreading.Function cannot access lockThis at all.

I’m not sure what you mean by *TestThreading.Function* not being able to access *lockThis*?! Again assume we call the code surrounded by lock ( located inside *TestThreading.Function* ) **C**.
If *TestThreading.Function* is static and thus there is only one room, but *lockThis* is non-static, and if we have the following definition:

```
 public class TestThreading
 {
    private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();

    public static  void Function()
    {

        lock (new TestThreading().lockThis)
        {
           // Access thread-sensitive resources.
        }
    }
 }
```

,then whenever some thread would access **room C**, it would use a new key. Thus, if 100 threads accessed **room C**, then same room would be opened using 100 different keys?! So the code does work, it just doesn’t make much sense, since there would be no synchronization at all between threads?!

> The scope of the lock, in this situation, is the individual instance of the class itself. This is opposed to crossing all instance of the specific class. You could have your lock cross all instances TestThreading by making lockThis static.

I was confused with the term *scope of the lock*, since I’ve interpret it as: if the *lockThis* was static, then all *TestThread* instances would share the same room (aka lock), even though *TestThread.Function* isn’t static. Assuming I understand it correctly now,  then  the term lock is referring to the key (thus lock doesn’t refer to the room?! ) used for opening the doors?

As such,  if we assume that *lockThis* is static and *TestThread.Function* is not static, then the scope of the key/lock is all *TestThread* instances, which  means that all *TestThread* instances share the same key and thus when one *TestThread* instance opens the door to its room using this key, the other instances won’t be able to open the doors to their rooms until first instance releases that key?

Third reply to David Morton

> No, if Function is static, then all TestThread instances would share the same room, if lockThis is static, then all TestThread instances would share the same key.

Do you agree that the word *lock* used in a sentence *scope of the lock* at least in a way refers to the key ( key being *lockThis* instance )?

> The room is the code that is executed within the lock, not the lockThis object itself, that's simply the key.

[Defense mode ON] That’s  what I’ve said in my last reply. ;) [Defense mode OFF]

Comment: In response to your response:  There is a significance.  If TestThreading.Function is static, then lockThis _has to be_ static, otherwise, TestThreading.Function cannot access lockThis at all.  Think about it this way... if the function is static, then there's only one room, and there can be only one key.  If the function is instance, then there can be several rooms (one per instance), but each room can either have it's own key (non-static lockThis) or it can share a key with all other rooms (static lockThis).  So, it does make a difference.

Comment: "Do you agree that the word lock used in a sentence scope of the lock at least in a way refers to the key ( key being lockThis instance )?" Yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The scope of the lock, in this situation, is the *individual instance* of the class itself.  This is opposed to crossing *all instance* of the specific class.  You could have your lock cross all instances TestThreading by making lockThis static.  That's what's meant by the "scope" of the lock: whether it's applicable to a single instance, or applicable to every instance of a particular type.
2. "Locking on object thisObject" simply means to use thisObject as the object that determines whether or not we're in the lock.  The term doesn't suggest that we "locked" the lockThis object.  I think your estimation is correct here. Other objects could still access lockThis from another thread, but they wouldn't be able to process code that is surrounded by a lock on *that* object.

Since we're responding to each other, here's a bit more information:

Let's take the "room and key" analogy you outlined above, and extend it for each and every possibility.  We have a few different situations:

1. static function, static lock object - This is analogous to having one room, with only one key.
2. instance function, static lock object - This would be like having several rooms that share the same key... like a master key, for example.
3. instance function, instance lock object - This would be like having several rooms, each with it's own key... like a dormitory or hotel.
4. static function, instance lock object - impossible.  You can't access an instance field from a static context.

Hopefully, the above scenarios outline how these would work together.

**In response to the second response**

> I’m not sure what you mean by TestThreading.Function not being able to access lockThis?!

It can't access a *useful* lockThis.  A static method locking on an instance that gets thrown away when the lock is finished is useless.  In the scenario you set up, each time the door is approached, the lock "gives away" a new key, and says "okay, I accept the key I just gave you... you can come on in".  In that situation, it's guarding the "room" too loosely, giving everyone access whenever they want it.  In other words, there's no reason to even have a lock statement in that second example. It's like the room has a dynamically increasing number of doors, used just once, that has the key taped to it.  An infinite number of people can enter whenever they want. There's no difference between your code and the following, really (there are, but this is so that you can hopefully get the concept:

```
public class TestThreading
{
    private object lockThis = new object();

    public static void Function() 
    {
        lockThis = new object();
        lock (lockThis)
        {
            // access something   
        }
    }
}
```

What I've done in that example above is basically *throw away and re-key the lock* right before I use it in the door.  That's not useful.  You're right, there wouldn't be any synchronization of threads, and in that sense, I would say that the code doesn't really work at all, as the whole point of the lock is to synchronize threads.

> if the lockThis was static, then all
>   TestThread instances would share the
>   same room (aka lock), even though
>   TestThread.Function isn’t static.
>   Assuming I understand it correctly
>   now, then the term lock is referring
>   to the key (thus lock doesn’t refer to
>   the room?! ) used for opening the
>   doors?

No, if *Function* is static, then all TestThread instances would share the same room, if lockThis is static, then all TestThread instances would share the same *key*.

```
lock (key)
{
   // room
}
```

The room is the code that is executed within the lock, not the lockThis object itself, that's simply the key.

> As such, if we assume that lockThis is
>   static and TestThread.Function is not
>   static, then the scope of the key/lock
>   is all TestThread instances, which
>   means that all TestThread instances
>   share the same key and thus when one
>   TestThread instance opens the door to
>   its room using this key, the other
>   instances won’t be able to open the
>   doors to their rooms until first
>   instance releases that key?

Yes.

Comment: In case you find the time - I've edited my post in response to your reply

Comment: In case you find the time - I’ve made a second ( and last ;) ) edit to my post in response to your reply to your post. In any case, I really appreciate your time and effort

Comment: I’ve updated my post just to ask you about what exactly you didn’t agree with in my analogy.  Anyways, thank you for having the patience and helping me understand all of this

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the differences in locking over static or non-static objects, consider:

```
public class TestThreading
{
    private object lockThis = new object();
    private static object lockStatic = new object();
    private Stream UIStream;
    private List<int> calcStuff;

    public void DoStuff1()
    {
        lock (lockThis)
        {
            // Do stuff with calcStuff that is unique to this instance
            // it's okay to have different instances calculating their own stuff
        }
    }

    public void DoStuff2()
    {
        lock (lockStatic)
        {
            // Do stuff with the UI,
            // which you don't want multiple threads accessing at once
        }
    }
}
```

especially in a situation like

```
var A = new TestThreading();
var B = new TestThreading();

((Action)(A.DoStuff1)).BeginInvoke(null,null); // These can go concurrently
((Action)(B.DoStuff1)).BeginInvoke(null,null); // just fine

((Action)(A.DoStuff1)).BeginInvoke(null,null); // These will have to wait
((Action)(A.DoStuff1)).BeginInvoke(null,null);

((Action)(A.DoStuff2)).BeginInvoke(null,null); // These will have to wait
((Action)(B.DoStuff2)).BeginInvoke(null,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

What that paragraph is talking about is what code has the ability to take the lock, not how long the lock is held (which that article refers to as lock duration).

Answer (score 1):

David Morton's answer seems correct to me, but for a greater reference, see this website: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)  It's a great resource for all things threading in C#, including examples of what **not** to do in a few cases.  Very clear IMO.

Answer (score 1):

a) Since every object of the TestThreading class will have it's own "lockThis" object, only that individual object will be in the scope of the lock b/c only that individual object can even reference "lockThis" (b/c it is private)

b) No, it means since the TestThreading object that called the lock is the only object that can "lock" the critical region (again, b/c it is private), "locking on object lockThis" means you are locking the TestThreading object using the lockThis private reference type.

For example, if instead you wrote this:

```
public class TestThreading
 {
     // private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();

     public void Function()
     {

         lock (this)
         {
            // Access thread-sensitive resources.
         }
     }
  }
```

Not only would the individual object be able to lock the object using the Function method, EVERY CLASS THAT HAS A REFERENCE to the TestThreading object in use can lock using the Function method, b/c the TestThreading object would presumably be at least "internal" if not "public".